# Copying a concatenated constant to the clipboard

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Is there a shortcut in IntelliJ to copy a concatenated constant into the clipboard?

For example, supposing I have this:

```
private static final String SQL = "my big " +
                                  "sql "+
                                  "statement";
```

Is there a way to copy `my big sql statement` (ie all concatenated together) to the clipboard?

Comment: ctrl+w selects block. This is the closest I got

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Press Alt-Enter on the string and select "Copy String concatenation text into clipboard" from the menu.

Comment: It removes all the " and + but does not put it on 1 line. There are still 3 lines

Comment: @Bentaye yes, you're correct, but that's more a problem witih my question than with what Idea does :)

Comment: The questions says nothing about putting the contents on 1 line.

Answer (score 2):

The `Join Lines` short cut can help, check the `Keymap` for your system (in IntelliJ Preferences), here is mine on Mac

[image: Keymap]

- Starting with

  ```
  private static final String SQL = "my big " +
                                    "sql "+
                                    "statement";
  ```
- Select the 3 lines and then `Ctrl+Shift+J`, you get

  ```
  private static final String SQL = "my big sql statement";
  ```
- Select your string and `Ctrl+C`, you now have your statement in the clipboard
- `Ctrl+Z` to go back to

  ```
  private static final String SQL = "my big " +
                                    "sql "+
                                    "statement";
  ```